# Eigenvalues of polynomials of a matrix and its inverse up to summation by identity

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, spectral-theory

There is a paper that I am reading and the following has been considered without proof: (Suppose $\lambda(.)$ defines the spectrum of a matrix and one can define a random variable on this spectrum say $Z$ for a given matrix $A$.):
$$\mathbb{E}\lambda(A(A+\nu I)^{-1})=\mathbb{E}\frac{Z}{Z+\nu}$$

I don't know how to prove it but I know the following fact:

For a given matrix $A$, and given polynomial $p(x)$, we have:
$\lambda(p(A))=\{p(\lambda_1),p(\lambda_2),p(\lambda_3),p(\lambda_4),...\}$
(As [multiset](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiset))

How can I proceed to prove something general for the polynomials of a matrix and its inverses up to summations by identity? Or even this special case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $v$ is a vector from the eigenspace $E_\alpha$ of $A$ then $Av=\alpha v$ and $(A+\nu I)v=(\alpha+\nu)v$ that is $v=(\alpha+\nu)(A+\nu I)^{-1}v$ for $\nu\notin-\sigma(A)$. Finally $$\forall\, v\in E_\lambda,\qquad A(A+\nu I)^{-1}v=\dfrac{\alpha}{\alpha+\nu}v$$
This means that on $\{Z=\alpha\}$, $Z$ takes the value $\lambda(A(A+\nu I)^{-1})=\dfrac{\alpha}{\alpha+\nu}$.Thus
$$\mathbb{E}(\lambda(A(A+\nu I)^{-1}))=\sum_{\alpha\in\sigma(A)}\dfrac{\alpha}{\alpha+\nu}\mathbb{P}(Z=\alpha)=\mathbb{E}\left(\frac{Z}{Z+\nu}\right).$$